# Getting phrases instead of words using Solr autosuggest

Tags: solrcloud, autosuggest

I am getting whole phrase instead of getting words on implementing
suggester in `solr`.

The configuration is like this

```
<searchComponent name="suggest"
    class="solr.SuggestComponent">
     
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">indexSuggester</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.FSTLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance</str>
        <str name="field">title_txt</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textSuggest</str>
        <str name="accuracy">0.7</str>
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.0001</float>
    </lst>
    </searchComponent>

    <requestHandler name="/suggest"
    class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
     
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
        <str name="suggest.dictionary">indexSuggester</str>
         
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
    </requestHandler>

    <fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSuggest"
    positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2"
            maxShingleSize="5" />
    </analyzer>

    <field name="title_txt" type="textSuggest" indexed="true"
        stored="true" />
```